# When does the unique_ptr get reset on this setter?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

```
class A
{
    ...
    B b;
}
```

When does the unique_ptr i passed in get removed?

```
void A::SetB( unique_ptr<B> b )
{
    this->b = *b;
} // At end of scope, is `b` now reset 
  // and the `B b` in class `A` just stores the value in it?
```

If the above answer is no, it doesn't get removed... would this remove it:

```
void A::SetB( unique_ptr<B> b )
{
    this->b = *move(b);
} // At end of scope, is `b` now reset
  // and the `B b` in class `A` just stores the value in it?
```

Or must i reset it myself if i wish it to be removed at that point:

```
void A::SetB( unique_ptr<B> b )
{
    this->b = *b;
    b.reset();
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `this->b`? If it is a `std::unique_ptr<B>`, then all of your examples cause compiler errors. If it is `B`, then then copy constructor is used to make a copy of it in all three cases.

Comment: The assignment in `SetB` copies the contents of the `B` object that `b` points to into `A::b`. At the end of the function, `b` goes out of scope and destroys the original; but the copy remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first two cases the `unique_ptr` gets reset when the function `SetB` returns. You don't leak any memory in either case, but what you're doing is odd.

In the first case

```
this->b = *b;
```

[`unique_ptr::operator*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator*) returns a reference to the managed object. So you're copy assigning the `B` instance contained in the `unique_ptr<B>` argument to your class' data member `b`.

The second case

```
this->b = *move(b);
```

behaves exactly the same as the first. All you've done different this time is invoke `unique_ptr::operator*` on a `unique_ptr<B>&&` ([`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) simply casts its argument to an rvalue reference).

In both cases the `unique_ptr` argument retains ownership of the `B` instance `SetB` was originally called with, and it'll destroy it when the function returns.

---

Your use case doesn't seem like one where you should be using `unique_ptr` at all, all you need is a setter. Probably the following

```
void A::SetB( B b )
{
    this->b = move(b);
}
```

Comment: I thought it would be nice to show ownership explicitly through the parameter. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 It really depends on what your use case is. If `A::b` were of type `unique_ptr<B>` then a setter for `b` that takes a `unique_ptr<B>` makes sense. You'd assume ownership of the managed object within the body (`this->b.swap(b);`). In your example you're forcing the caller to dynamically allocate a `B`, place it in a `unique_ptr` and call your setter, but then you make a copy and throw away the original. See why that doesn't make sense?